# When we use following string then error is produced , help me for solution

Tags: sql

```
selectString = @"SELECT StudentRegistrationInformation.registrationNo,
                        StudentRegistrationInformation.firstName,
                        StudentRegistrationInformation.lastName,
                        StudentPayment.subjectName,
                        sum(StudentPayment.feeReceived) AS totalReceivedFee
                 FROM StudentRegistrationInformation
                 INNER JOIN StudentPayment 
                     ON StudentPayment.registrationNo =
                            StudentRegistrationInformation.registrationNo";
```

Error:

> *Column 'StudentRegistrationInformation.registrationNo' is invalid in
>   the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate
>   function or the GROUP BY clause.*

Comment: This has nothing to do with c#, it's purely SQL problem. Fixed tags.

Comment: Isn't the error message clear enough ?

Comment: If you remove `sum(StudentPayment.feeReceived)` it should work. `Sum` is an aggregate function.

Answer (score 2):

You're using an aggregate function in your query. Therefore, your query needs to know how to group the rest of the results. It's as easy as adding the following to the end of your query:

```
GROUP BY StudentRegistrationInformation.registrationNo,
         StudentRegistrationInformation.firstName,
         StudentRegistrationInformation.lastName,
         StudentPayment.subjectName
```

Answer (score 0):

you must add GroupBy in the end of your query on clumns in the select without aggregation functions

```
SELECT StudentRegistrationInformation.registrationNo,
                                            StudentRegistrationInformation.firstName,
                                            StudentRegistrationInformation.lastName,
                                            StudentPayment.subjectName,
                                            sum(StudentPayment.feeReceived) AS        totalReceivedFee
                                       FROM StudentRegistrationInformation
                                            INNER JOIN StudentPayment ON
                                            StudentPayment.registrationNo=StudentRegistrationInformation.registrationNo

GROUP BY tudentRegistrationInformation.registrationNo,
                                            StudentRegistrationInformation.firstName,
                                            StudentRegistrationInformation.lastName,
                                            StudentPayment.subjectName
```

Comment: I'am happy  to help you Unique

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using the aggregate function "sum", you need to add

```
GROUP BY StudentRegistrationInformation.registrationNo,
         StudentRegistrationInformation.firstName,
         StudentRegistrationInformation.lastName,
         StudentPayment.subjectName
```

To your SQL string.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables was typing on my iPhone and didn't copy the complete string from the question :). Fixed now.